# If statement Makefile tcsh

Tags: makefile, csh, tcsh

I want something like :

```
my_rule:
       if($(VAR) == $@) then
             echo 'ok'
       else
             echo 'ko'
       endif
```

I have to use **tsch** but I know that Makefile use **sh**, so I really wonder if I have to use sh or tcsh if statement syntax here... ?
The correct syntax for if statement in a **tsch script** is (I checked) :

```
#!/bin/csh

if(3 == 3) then
    echo 'yes'
else
    echo 'no'
endif
```

I tried to put `;` and `\` everywhere in my Makefile but nothing work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell is taken from the variable `SHELL`, and if not specified, defaults to `/bin/sh`.   Assuming you're not overriding the shell, then your syntax would be:

```
my_rule:
       if [ "$(VAR)" == "$@" ]; then \
         echo 'ok'; \
       else \
         echo 'ko'; \
       fi
```

You need to use the `\`'s to concatenate the lines into a single recipe line.  Notice this does not introduce actual newlines, so you also have to manually terminate each command with a `;`.    Finally, put quotes around the variables, so that if one happens to be blank, you don't get a syntax error.

Comment: ok so I have to use the syntax of the shell define in the SHELL variable. thx